# sharing definitions across guard patterns

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching, helper

Say I have a function:

```
arbitrary :: String -> String -> Maybe String
arbitrary st1 st2 | (st1 == st2) = Just "foo"
                  | (arbitrarily_complex_calculation == 7) = Nothing
                  | otherwise = Just $ show arbitrarily_complex_calculation
```

How can I share arbitrarily complex_calculation across the two guard blocks? Can this be done via a `let` / `where` or do I have to write a helper function?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, a `where` clause is valid (and often used) with guards:

```
arbitrary :: String -> String -> Maybe String
arbitrary st1 st2 
  | st1 == st2 = Just "foo"
  | acc ==  7  = Nothing
  | otherwise  = Just $ show acc
 where 
   acc = arbitrarily_complex_calculation
```

Comment: And without the "where"? There could still be sharing by CSE.

Comment: @d8d0d65b3f7cf42 Unless `arbitrary_complex_calculation` has a polymorphic type (which would mess with the `Show` instance, though). Also, GHC [uses CSE only sparsely](https://wiki.haskell.org/GHC/FAQ#Does_GHC_do_common_subexpression_elimination.3F) (but I don't know whether this still holds in GHC 7.10+).